# What flight simulator software did Captain Zaharie Ahmad Shah use?

Tags: flight-simulator

During the investigation of [Malaysia Airlines Flight 370](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malaysia_Airlines_Flight_370), it was revealed that Captain Zaharie Ahmad Shah had a sophisticated home-built flight simulator setup.

[image: Flight Simulator]

*([article source](http://therearenosunglasses.wordpress.com/2014/03/16/malaysian-investigators-focus-upon-politically-active-pilot-zaharies/))*

What flight simulator software is he using here?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Based on the red little strip (notification bar) on the bottom of the instrument panel in the middle, it must be either [Microsoft Flight Simulator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Flight_Simulator) or [Lockheed Martin Prepar3d](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_Martin_Prepar3D). The red notifiation bar is specific to Flight Simulator 2004 (FS9) and Flight Simulator X (FSX). Laminar Research's [X-Plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Plane_%28simulator%29) uses a different graphics engine and would not have produced a scenery that looks like on the three outside view screens.

The source is not really quotable, but if the name and picture can be taken a proof, then Mr Shah himself writes on the [X-Sim.de Forum](http://www.x-sim.de/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=20&start=110) about FS9 and FSX being used:

> Elo guys,
>   zaharie here.... pls to join x-sim. About a month ago I finish assembly of FSX and FS9 with
>   6 monitors .... with the latest graphic card ( 2 pieces of asus 7970) on one cpu awesome view on 3 panasonic 32 in. LCD HDMI
>   and 3 touchscreen Dell 21 inches for main (MCP) , center pedestal, overhead panel.
>   time to take to the next level of simulation.Motion! looking for buddies to share this passion.
>   Capt Zaharie Ahmad Shah
>   BOEING 777 MALAYSIA AIRLINES

Answer based on own experience with all 3 simulators/publishers.

Comment: I've only ever played around with FlightGear a little bit, and I know that it is not as sophisticated as MS Flight Simulator, but I believe that it also has the red notification bar as seen in the screenshot.

Comment: If you an believe google and this is not fake, then Mr Zacharie himself writes here about FSX and FS9 being used:
http://www.x-sim.de/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=20&start=110

Comment: Just found this question, PMDG (a group that produces a 777 addon for FSX/P3D) [confirmed that capt. Zaharie was one of their customers](http://www.avsim.com/topic/436853-pmdg-simulations-comments-on-the-loss-of-mh-370/)